# RDS Monitoring using PMM2, Missing Host Metrics for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, monitoring, percona, pmm-server

I am using [PMM2](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management) for monitoring all my RDS instances.

I added Postgres as a remote database, But by [adding a database as remote](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/remote-instance.html) in PMM2 we miss host-level metrics like CPU, Memory etc. What is the recommended way of adding Postgres (RDS) or a way to inject missing metrics to get the complete Node Summary?

Answer (score 0):

We have also faced the same issue.

In PMM1, we had the cloud-watch as data-source, which was used get the host-level metrics. Now, in PMM2, this has been removed; hence, you can't get the metrics.

To get the metrics, add cloud-watch source plugin and import the dashboard from PMM1.